# after adding dynamic row i am not able to send data using php

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, mysql

i have made one form in table form which adds row dynamically but when i submit after filling data it gets only one data row which was filled last.

please help me out to get all data in data table for mysql.

here is my html code

```js
 var count = "1";
  function addRow(in_tbl_name)
  {
    var tbody = document.getElementById(in_tbl_name).getElementsByTagName("TBODY")[0];
    // create row
    var row = document.createElement("TR");
    // create table cell 1
    var td1 = document.createElement("TD")
    var strHtml1 = "<INPUT TYPE=\"text\" NAME=\"r_name\"PLACEHOLDER=\"Name\" >";
  
   
    td1.innerHTML = strHtml1.replace(/!count!/g,count);
    // create table cell 2
    var td2 = document.createElement("TD")
    var strHtml2 = "<INPUT TYPE=\"text\" NAME=\"r_desc\" PLACEHOLDER=\"description\" >";
    td2.innerHTML = strHtml2.replace(/!count!/g,count);
    // create table cell 3
    var td3 = document.createElement("TD")
    var strHtml3 = "<INPUT TYPE=\"text\" NAME=\"r_qty\" PLACEHOLDER=\"QTY\" NINPUT=\"calculate()\">";
    td3.innerHTML = strHtml3.replace(/!count!/g,count);
    // create table cell 4
    var td4 = document.createElement("TD")
    var strHtml4 = "<INPUT TYPE=\"text\" NAME=\"r_RATE\" PLACEHOLDER=\"rate\" ONINPUT=\"calculate()\" >";
    td4.innerHTML = strHtml4.replace(/!count!/g,count);
    // create table cell 5
   
  // create table cell 4
    var td5 = document.createElement("TD")
    var strHtml5 = "<INPUT TYPE=\"Button\" CLASS=\"Button\" onClick=\"delRow()\" VALUE=\"Delete Row\">";
 
    td5.innerHTML = strHtml5.replace(/!count!/g,count);
 
    // append data to row
    row.appendChild(td1);
    row.appendChild(td2);
    row.appendChild(td3);
    row.appendChild(td4);
    row.appendChild(td5);
 
    // add to count variable
    count = parseInt(count) + 1;
    // append row to table
    tbody.appendChild(row);
  }
  function delRow()
  {
    var current = window.event.srcElement;
    //here we will delete the line
    while ( (current = current.parentElement)  && current.tagName !="TR");
         current.parentElement.removeChild(current);
  }
```

```html
 <div class="table-responsive">
                  
   <table  ID="tblPets" class="table  table-bordered table-hover">  
  
  <thead>  
  
        <tr>  
  
            <th><center>Row material Name</center></th> 
   <th><center>Description</center></th> 
            
            <th><center>Qty.</center></th> 
           
            <th><center>Rate</center></th> 
           
            <th><center><INPUT TYPE="Button" onClick="addRow('tblPets')" VALUE="Add Row"></center></th>  

   
   
        </tr>  
  </thead>
  
   <tbody >
  <tr>  
  <form action="add_item - Copy.php" method="post">
            <th><INPUT TYPE="text" NAME="r_name" PLACEHOLDER="Name"></th> 
   <th><INPUT TYPE="text" NAME="r_desc" PLACEHOLDER="description" ></th> 
            
            <th><INPUT TYPE="text" NAME="r_qty" PLACEHOLDER="QTY" ONINPUT="calculate()" ></th> 
           
            <th><INPUT TYPE="text" NAME="r_RATE" PLACEHOLDER="rate" ONINPUT="calculate()"></th> 
            <th></th>  

        </tr>
  </tbody>
    <tfoot>
    <tr>
      <td> <input type="submit" name="sub" value="Submit"></td>
      <td></td>
    </tr>
  </tfoot>
  </form>
        
  
  
                                </table>
  
  </div>
```

here is php code for insert data

```
    if(isset($_POST['sub'])) { 


    $r_nm=$_POST['r_name'];

    $r_qty=$_POST['r_qty'];
    $r_rate=$_POST['r_RATE'];
$insert_rm="insert into tbl_row_material (rm_name,rm_qty, rm_rate) VALUE ('$r_nm','$r_qty','$r_rate')"; 
mysqli_query($dbcon,$insert_rm);
}
```

Comment: Keep your elements name in array format `name=xyz[]`

Comment: @Richie than do i have to change insert query?

Comment: After that you will start getting data in array format. there will be some minor changes. and also you are creating multiple forms here check you code.

Comment: i want all data in saprate row of mysql not all in one single feild..

Comment: yes i tried that i am getting Array in data field

Comment: @Richie if i take an array than do i have to give condition in foreach loop arround insert query?

Comment: yes you have to execute your query in loop.

Comment: can you give me code

Answer (score 0):

try this

```
if(isset($_POST['sub'])) 
 { 
    $r_nm=$_POST['r_name'];
    $r_qty=$_POST['r_qty'];
    $r_rate=$_POST['r_RATE'];

    $insert_rm="insert into tbl_row_material (rm_name,rm_qty, rm_rate) VALUES ('$r_nm','$r_qty','$r_rate')";  
    mysqli_query($dbcon,$insert_rm); 
}
```

Comment: you using only `VALUE ` i'm change to `VALUES`

Comment: dosent make any diffrance i changed value to values

Comment: check this `$result =  mysqli_query($dbcon,$insert_rm); var_dump($result)`

Comment: same result dosent make any diffrance

Comment: `var_dump($result)` return` true` or` false` value you check that

Comment: so you checke  mysql table value inserted or not

Comment: i think i need to give for each loop arround insert query. but i dont know where to place and how to apply code

Comment: data table gets value but only the last inserted value is taken from the table

Comment: which table html or mysql??

Comment: html table gives value to sql

Comment: i think you need to use both insert and select query

Answer (score 0):

Place `<form>` tag above `<table>` tag

and also place `</form>` tag below `</table>` tag

Comment: why are you taking form name like add_item - Copy.php replace filename with add_item.php and also in form action specify that name

Answer (score 0):

As you are getting data in array, you can use the below code to insert. I have not tested this code there might be any syntax error.

```
$r_nm = $_POST['r_name'];
$r_qty=$_POST['r_qty'];
$r_rate=$_POST['r_RATE'];

foreach($r_nm as $key=>$val){
   //Your inser query here
   $insert_rm= "insert into tbl_row_material (rm_name,rm_qty, rm_rate) VALUE ($val,$r_qty[$key],$r_rate[$key])"; 
   mysqli_query($dbcon,$insert_rm);
}
```